# How to get the value of previous `<input type="text">` in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I get the ID of the upper `<td>`’s `<input>` on click, in the `up` function? I tried so many ways like parent ID and previous ID but can not get that id.

```js
function up(id) {
  var data = $(this).prev("input[type=text]").attr('id');

  alert(data)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="row">
      <input class="latest" id="old" type="text" name="">
    </td>
    <td class="second margin_t8">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="col-md-12"  onclick="up(this);">up</a>
    </td>
    <td class="first margin_t8">
      <input class="latest" id="news" type="text" name="" value="data">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In that case, I get `undefined`. I want to get the previous `<input>` id in the alert. I need to find the data by id not by class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the sender (which element is calling the function) as an argument to the function like :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <td class="row">
    <input class="latest" id="old"  type="text" name="" >
  </td>
  <td class="second  margin_t8">

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="col-md-12"  onclick="up(this);"></a>

  </td>
  <td class="first margin_t8">
    <input class="latest" id="news"  type="text" name="" value="data">
  </td>


</table>
<script>
  function up(sender) {
 
    var data = $(sender).prev("tr").find("input[type=text].latest").attr('id');
    alert(data);
  }
</script>
```

Hope this helps in getting the previous row's input's id!!

Comment: returning the same click event id not previous text box id

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but are you sure the one that i ve finally edited is not working?

Comment: From Ur code i m getting the current click id ..not getting id of previous one

Comment: so you need the previous row's input id?

Comment: Thanx its working now thanx sanatasthyan.. and 1 more ques please if i want the after row's input id?  then what shud i need to do???

Comment: to get the next row's input's id?? you need to replace .prev("tr") with .next("tr")

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by second case?

Comment: when i re click on that... like if i get the first value it change the td but in second case it returning the same td id twice for both case

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `this` is not pointing to the button which is clicked in this case as you don't use jQuery to add the event handler. However, you can use `event.target` to get the clicked element. Also, `.prev()` will return the previous element to the `i` tag which is `undefined` as it does not have any siblings.

**Updated:**

```
function up(id){
  var data = $(event.target).closest('td').prev().find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
  alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Now I see that your structure is pretty weird. I'd suggest to place the `i` tags into a separate `a` tag and put the onclick handler on the `a` tag. Then, I think my code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out (not tested)

`var data=$(this).closest('.form-grid-view-row').first().children("input[type=text]").attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function up(element) {
      var data = $(element).parent().prev().find("input[type=text]").attr('id');
      alert(data)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <td class="row">
    <input class="latest" id="old"  type="text" name="" >
  </td>
  <td class="second  margin_t8">

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="col-md-12"  onclick="up(this);">ss</a>

  </td>
  <td class="first margin_t8">
    <input class="latest" id="news"  type="text" name="" value="data">
  </td>


</table>
```